# what's alternative hjsplit software for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've downloaded [hjsplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/linux/) for linux on official website but when I tried it's doesn't working. can anyone give me recommendation alternative for join or split file software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` command is part of Ubuntu core.

Example usage here http://blulin.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/split-and-join-large-files-in-gnulinux-just-using-terminal/